# Visual studio Unable to load page in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to debug my web application but when Debug start the browser page start loading and then automatically stops with the error Unable to load page.
I have tried loading localhost with different port number but failed.
Please help here is the screenshot.

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: In VS top menu, go to project > your proj Properties and take a screen shot of the Web tab for us.

Comment: In your page inspector it is telling you that you have a cert error btw

Comment: how to solve certifiecate error?

Comment: Hmm, actually that is a captive portal page, like what you would see if you were at a hotel and needed to get their passcode before you went on the internet. Do you have resources that are loaded up on your intranet or soemthing where you have to have vpn on? Here is the normal fun ssl cert crap btw although i dont think it is your problem now looking at those tags in your inspector: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/a/

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Wasn't an answer, more of a wth observation. You should probably post a screenshot of that web tab like I asked so we can see what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

What does the application output from Visual Studio say when it runs the application?